# how to prevent convert received datetime property from client to utc

Tags: asp.net-core

I used a RestfulApi to get data from client. The DateTime type value sent from client is at +8 time zone. But the back-up will convert it to UTC automatically. How to prevent this conversion?

Comment: Can you share more about your RestfulApi ?

Comment: at front end I send a string type value as a property in a class, and in the back end receive this property as a DateTime type. It seems the back end will convert this value automatically to UTC value rather than keep the origin +8 time zone value